# How to calculate and use latest updated object in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attributes, mongoid

I have `Projelements`, which are like:

- `Milestone`
- `Task`
- ... etc ...

Each `Projelement` can have one or more embedded `Comments` (thanks to `Mongoid`).

I want to be able to easily say:

*Give me a list of `Projelements` sorted by when they were last updated*

Where `last_updated` for a `Projelement` is the larger of:

- `this_projelement.updated_at` OR
- `if this_projelement.comments.count > 0 then this_projelement.comments.last.updated_at`

I can create a `Projelement` class method `last_updated_at` with the above logic.

But what I really want to end up with is doing a query of my `Projelements`, retrieving the last updated `Projelement` using the above logic, in the same way as you'd do a query using an **attribute**.

Previously, I tried using an attribute-only approach:

Tried using the `updated_at` attribute: this timestamp is updated if you update a `Projelement`'s attributes, but is not updated if you update the embedded `Comments`. So I could manually update `this_projelement.updated_at` whenever a `Comment` is added. But the design feels brittle.

Also thought about having a separate attribute (e.g. `last_updated_at`) so that existing semantics of `updated_at` are not messed with. But design also feels brittle.

What would be the Rails way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With MongoDB, there are no solution to order by some embedded document field.

In your case, the solution to do a callback before_save in your Comment and update an attribute in your parent document seem the most reasonnable technic.